# SQL: GROUP BY for number ranges?

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm a first time poster and new to SQL, as are my colleagues.
I have a column of numbers (let's just call it "numbers") and the values in it range from 1-9999.
I need to create a grouping column (let's call it "numbers level") and assign the values of AA to all numbers from 1-999, BB from 1000-6999 and CC for 7000-9999.
So, the final output would look like below (output does not need to be ordered):

```
numbers      |   numbers level
-------------------------------------
   136       |        AA
  2935       |        BB
  4288       |        BB
  8987       |        CC
  436        |        AA
  3737       |        BB
```

Is there any easy way to script this, i.e.: by using a GROUP BY clause?
Or does that grouping column have to exist already and I need to just populate it with a command?

Please let me know if my question wreaks of cluelessness and I'll clarify the best I can.

Comment: There is no grouping to be done, you should generate the "numbers level" column with a CASE statement.   Google up on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be easiest with a case statement (assuming you're using sql-server; if not, please add tags for the correct version).

```
Select [Numbers]
  , case when [Numbers] between 1 and 999 then 'AA'
         when [Numbers] between 1000 and 6999 then 'BB'
         when [Numbers] between 7000 and 9999 then 'CC'
    end as [Numbers Level]
from MyTable
```

If any of your numbers don't fall into those ranges, it will return NULL - use `else` if you want a different result when this happens.

Comment: This worked as needed! Thank you so much on helping with my first steps into SQL.

Comment: @StanDarsh Happy to help!  If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The grouping column has to exist, but you could use a `case` instead.

```
select nr,
       case when nr <= 999 then 'AA'
            when nr <= 7000 then 'BB'
       else 'CC'
       end as NrLevel
from   Numbers
```

Comment: I agree that this solution will work. However moving When statement up or down will screw everything.

Comment: True. So don't do that. You'll find that it also won't work if you move `from Numbers` above `select nr`.

Comment: It will also mask problems, if there are numbers outside the expected range, by assigning all of those values 'CC' as well.

Comment: @APH, a fair point. The specs say *"and the values in it range from 1-9999"*. Nevertheless, it can't hurt to use a more defensive implementation, and yours is certainly that, so +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I agree the specs say this should never happen, but the data I work with normally makes me paranoid.

Comment: I know, in a real life scenario I would be more defensive to, but in this case I thought the main issue would be to show the `case`. But your `between .. and ..` is easer on the eyes too. I use it to little, because I can never remember if the range is up to or including. ;)

Comment: Haha, glad to know I'm not the only one who has that problem.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a group here, you can accomplish it using a simple case statement.

```
SELECT number,
CASE WHEN number between 1 and 999 THEN 'AA'
     WHEN number between 1000 and 6999 THEN 'BB'
     WHEN number between 7000 and 9999 then 'CC'
     END numbers_level
from Number_table
```

Comment: Please avoid duplicate answers

Comment: Well that's kinda hard to do when everybody answers within 59 seconds of each other.

Comment: really... posted less than a minutes before me.. sorry I don't refresh my browser every 10 sec to avoid it...